How to break the loop only if email subject does not contain today or yesterday date
I'm reading this document regarding connecting to my IMAP server and read the emails, but I have some issues.
Currently I have around 10K emails and it's growing (I delete old emails weekly, but they're still a lot), and in this part of the code, it fetches all emails:
res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")

My emails have static subject format like this:
StaticText1 - SUBJECT - SentDateYYYY-MM-DD Hour:Minute
StaticText2 - SUBJECT - SentDateYYYY-MM-DD Hour:Minute

Let's suppose a list like this for simplicity:
dates = ['2024-07-16', '2024-07-16', '2024-07-16', '2024-07-16', '2024-07-16', '2024-07-16', '2024-07-16', '2024-07-15', '2024-07-15', '2024-07-15', '2024-07-15', '2024-07-15', '2024-07-15', '2024-07-15', '2024-07-15', '2024-07-14', '2024-07-14', '2024-07-14', '2024-07-14', '2024-07-14', '2024-07-14', '2024-07-13', '2024-07-13', '2024-07-13', '2024-07-13', '2024-07-13', '2024-07-13', '2024-07-13']

So, let's say reading each emails take at least 0.1 second, and that will be a huge time for 10K emails.
I read emails in my code from the latest to the oldest.
I'm going to reach this:
if datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') in subject or (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') in subject:
  # then read email
  print(email)
else:
 # as soon as it reaches an email which has 2024-07-14, it breaks the loop and shouldn't try anything further
  break

The main question is, is that even possible?
Update1
To clarify, I know this but it reads each email and if it doesn't contain the date, breaks and goes to another email (which is not excepted):
for subject in emails:
  if today in subject or yesterday in subject:
    print(subject)


Yes, it's possible. The if statement is wrong, though, since the ... in subject should be on both sides of the or; otherwise it'll always evaluate to True, since datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') is always true.
To make it simpler to read:
now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
yesterday = (now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

for mail in mails:
    subject = mail.subject
    if not (today in subject or yesterday in subject):
        break  # all done!
    # ... process mail


Thanks, I added the update whole you were answering. Would you please see that? I think it's what I said and I think it doesn't work in this case. Am I wrong?

Oops, I had some errors in my first if. I corrected because I didn't pay enough attention to that while writing the question

@Saeed I'm not following. Your edit doesn't have a break.

Doesn't your code goes through all emails? Do I misunderstood? I tried your code, but it still goes through other emails. I think I got another way.

Thanks, I used your code and added some changes to my own version and now it works:)

I would approach this task differently as

My emails have static subject format like this:
StaticText1 - SUBJECT - SentDateYYYY-MM-DD Hour:Minute
StaticText2 - SUBJECT - SentDateYYYY-MM-DD Hour:Minute


You might easily extract that YYYY-MM-DD by splitting and taking 2nd element from end e.g.
subject = "Static - Able - 2024-01-01 12:34"
datestr = subject.split()[-2]
print(datestr)  # 2024-01-01

which you then can convert into datetime.datetime object
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, "%Y-%m-%d")

and compute delta with today
delta = datetime.date.today() - dt.date()

and access .days attribute
print(delta.days)  # 197

value of which is integer. This allows you to easily adjust number of days.
